# Do not show match that contains a string

Tags: regex, groovy

Guys I have the following case:

```
def AllEnviroments = ['company-test', 'MYTEST-1234', 'company-somethingelse-something']
def EnviromentChoices = (AllEnviroments =~  /company-.*|MYTEST/).findAll().collect().sort()
```

How to exclude from this regex strings that have ” something ” or whatever it will be in it's place inside it so it will print only company test and DPDHLPA

Expected result :
PRINT company-test and mytest-1234
and **NOT** "company-something"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
def AllEnviroments = ['company-test', 'MYTEST-1234', 'company-somethingelse-something']
def EnviromentChoices = AllEnviroments.findAll { it =~ /company-(?!something).*|MYTEST/ }.sort()
print(EnviromentChoices)
// => [MYTEST-1234, company-test]
```

Note that the `.findAll` is run directly on the string array where the regex is updated with a negative lookahead to avoid matching any strings where `something` comes directly after `company-`.

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/mNH8VL).

Comment: That works, what I failed to mention and added to my question is that it is not always sure if it will be company-something, it could company-onething-secondthing-anotherthing. I always to exclude based on a specific word

Comment: @WhoAmI So, the `something` should not be at the end of string? Remove `$` from the lookahead, see updated demo at https://ideone.com/mNH8VL

Comment: One question is just for the sake can it be better. Is there a way to make the same regex, but not rely on the "-". Just check if anywhere in the string "something" exists

Comment: @WhoAmI I think you mean `/^(?!.*something).*(?:company-|MYTEST)/`

Comment: You are my hero. Wish I understood better how this works: ^(?!.*something).* . But that is exactly what was needed. Thanks a lot

Comment: @WhoAmI It is one of the most common regexps. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57301144/3832970).

Comment: Why does your code work with findAll(it =~) , but not    def EnviromentChoices = (AllEnviroments =~ /company-(?!something|another|other).*|DPDHLPA-.*/ ).findAll().collect().sort() . I receive null result like that. Groovy is so confusing :D

Comment: @WhoAmI Nothing confusing here, a regex can only be applied to a *string*. Your `AllEnviroments` is a *list* or *array*. So, it is coerced to a string before the regex can start looking for matches. And it is not what you want. You want to apply the regex on each item in the array and only get those that match.